# Maximum gap among N points on a circle

Tags: probability, circles

If $N$ points on the circumference of a circle are chosen at random, what is the probability $F(\theta)$ that the maximum gap between neighboring points is at least $\theta$?  Because the gaps sum to $2\pi$, the maximum must be at least $2\pi/N$, so $$F(\theta)=1 \text{  for } \theta\le\frac{2\pi}{N}.$$  At the other extreme, the solution to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/n-points-on-a-circle) shows that $$F(\theta) = N\left(1 - \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right)^{N-1} \text{  for } \theta\ge\pi.$$ 
Is there a closed-form solution for any other values of $\theta$?

---

**Update:** The general closed-form solution is given in the answer below.  In terms of the notation in the question, it is
$$
F(\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} (-1)^{k-1} {N\choose k} \left(1 - \frac{k \theta}{2\pi}\right)^{N-1},
$$
where $K = \min(N, \lfloor{2\pi/\theta}\rfloor)$.  This reduces to the limiting cases given in the question when $\theta \le 2\pi/N$ (in which case $K=N$) and when $\theta \ge \pi$ (in which case $K=1$).

Comment: See Mike Spivey's answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52493/expected-second-moment-for-random-points-on-a-circle

Comment: The post in Shai's comment nailed it. (I was doing something similtar to James Martin there) Should this be closed as duplicated (in mathoverflow?)

Comment: @leonbloy: I'm not sure what the policy is about duplicating questions from MO.  It might be somewhere in meta, but I don't have time to chase it down now because I have to run to class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shai Covo indicates, this is given in my answer to the recent Math Overflow question "[Expected Second Moment for Random Points on a Circle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52493/expected-second-moment-for-random-points-on-a-circle/52548#52548)."

For a unit circle, the answer is
$$F(x) = n(1-x)^{n-1} - \binom{n}{2} (1 - 2x)^{n-1} + \cdots + (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} (1 - kx)^{n-1} + \cdots,$$ 
where the sum continues until $kx > 1$.

For the derivation see the MO answer.  It leans heavily on Section 6.4 ("Random Division of an Interval") in David and Nagaraja's *[Order Statistics](http://books.google.com/books?id=bdhzFXg6xFkC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=david+and+nagaraja+order+statistics+division+of+random+interval&source=bl&ots=OaK1s7x7Yj&sig=L6JuApcAHkMRTMfHfxXtNKfBvZw&hl=en&ei=VB4_Tbz1JIfCsAOIrpziBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, pages 133-137, and the corresponding exercises on pages 153-155.

The result was apparently first published by Ronald Fisher in "[Tests of Significance in Harmonic Analysis](http://www.jstor.org/stable/95247)," *Proceedings of the Royal Society of London, Series A*, 1929, pp 54-59.  (My apologies that this is a JSTOR link and not one that is freely available.)